# How to identify which app is reading from my disk

Tags: performance, resource-monitoring

Except for disabling one app at a time or all at once and then enable them all slowly again (The Elimination method) - How do I identify what app is reading my disk ?

it happens periodically and therefore very hard to debug.

What happens is that the phone slows down to an almost unusable state and when opening "System Monitor" (3rd party app) i see that the Disk is reading at 90MB/s. But i cant see WHAT APP is reading !

I've looked everywhere for monitor apps but haven't been able to find anything useful. None of the monitor apps i've found shows the CPU / IO usage of other apps, seems like Android 7.0 is limited in this aspect.

My phone (Sony Z5 Compact, Android 7.0) is NOT rooted !

Comment: See if [apps mentioned in first three questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A131553+system+monitor) help you - I don't have Nougat to verify

Comment: Thanks - but none of them show disk IO per app :(

Comment: Did you resolve this? I have the same problem. I found an iotop port however it requires root

Comment: Hi, no, not really..   AccuBattery helped as well as system monitor..  But it was pure guess work that narrowed down a Sony app that killed the phone.